# Bluemail - How to set user name and password

Tags: ibm-cloud

I call the service from `app.js` with below details but get response as

```
"description":"Not authorized"
```

Note that my username and password are correct but I may not be passing these correctly hence need help.

```
var options = {
      host: 'bluemail.w3ibm.mybluemix.net',
      port: 443,
      path: '/rest/v2/emails',
      method: 'POST',  
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf8",
            "username": "xxxxx",
            "password": "xxxxxx"
      }

    };
```

Comment: please ask this at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/ -- w3ibm is an internal Bluemix instance